# How much can NEDB with expressjs handle? Will it be suitable for this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, nedb

I'm using react and nodejs with express to create a simple site. I'm relatively familiar with nedb as a super lightweight database as it is a lot simpler and easier to set up.

I'm only expecting between 1000 - 5000 entries into the database and I doubt it will all be concurrent. Most probably over the duration of a couples hours.

The data will simply look a bit like this -

{"value":"0x5ECbbdA785b2db76DF360A7079d80FA77af81eF1", "twitter_handle":"@twitter", "_id":"057xMD9hVtKgk5Kd"}

Just want to make sure that the server/db won't fail. There might be a couple thousand users on the site at one time.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/issues/220

Comment: There's not much of a way to "make sure the server/db won't fail"--you should test it under load expectations. Whether or not it should be used for **your** application is a difficult question to answer under the best of circumstances. It may be just fine if it meets your needs.